# How did Naruto learn the Teleportation Jutsu?

Tags: naruto

I distinctly remember that scene from the anime where Naruto has just learned to control the Nine Tail's chakra. He immediately senses Kisame hiding in the sword and goes on to teleport to him and give him a good punch.

Has it ever been explained how he suddenly knows how to use this jutsu? Is it maybe just the body flicker technique that was taken to new heights because he now has all this extra chakra or is it the teleportation jutsu in the same vain his father used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are talking about [Chapter 505](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/The_Nine-Tails'_Chakra,_Freed!!):

> Naruto Uzumaki completes his training of gaining the Nine-Tails'
>   chakra inside of him. Before Yamato, Naruto, and Killer B leave,
>   Naruto senses Kisame Hoshigaki inside Samehada. Samehada springs into
>   action but Naruto used his right hand to smash Kisame.

There is no way that Naruto has used teleportation technique. But when someone does jinchūriki transformation, then according to [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails_Chakra_Mode):

> The user's physical abilities are enhanced while the mode is active,
>   with greater enhancements coming from using more of the Nine-Tails'
>   chakra.

So by simply doing a jinchūriki transformation, I don't think he will be able to teleport all of a sudden, and there is also nothing in wiki which states that he was able to do teleportation. **So it was his greater speed!**

Comment: Yeah but in the anime yamato mentions that he is not yet at the 4th hokage's level which at the very least alludes to him being able to use it.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that Naruto can perform teleportation technique too. And also in case of 4th Hokage he was able to teleport himself by using that special sealed kunai. See [this](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_Technique)

Comment: @NeilMeyer Naruto's speed will never match the 4th Hokages Teleportation Jutsu because its not teleportation. Naruto however was so fast that it almost appeared as if he Teleported to the much slower Yamato. Recall that the 4th Raikage could keep up with Naruto, but had to try and Outsmart Minato

Answer (score 0):

Well you see, naruto was able to use a body flicker technique after he learnt to control the kyubii or nine tails he used the teleportation jutsu twice against rikage and kisame hushigaki although it wasn't as perfect as his dads